# Sub-menu closes the menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a menu that shows the sub-menu just when clicked, not on hover.
I found lots of codes in the web but the one below was the cleaner and it works.
The problem is that when I click the sub-menu item it closes the menu and don't open the URL.

As the code is very condensed, I know this must be a small detail that I can't see.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-item-has-children").click(function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu').not($(this).children(".sub-menu").toggle()).hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Solved" this doing what DGS told, but I had to make custom links for the top item WITHOUT url, just the <a> tag.
That's not the best solution, but may be the fastest in the rush.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

Lines cause the default behaviour of following the link to not work.

These also fire when the event bubbles up from the inner elements. In order to check whether they should be triggered you can do the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-item-has-children").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('li').hasClass('menu-item-has-children')) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu').not($(this).children(".sub-menu").toggle()).hide();
    });
});
```

This will check which actual element triggered the event.

Comment: But I need the top item (.menu-item-has-children) to not go to their URL.

Comment: Ahh, please post a jsfiddle with your code. It is likely that your event handler you posted is catching the click events on the top item